# Calculating total bytes to download using WebClient()

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, webclient, progress

The variable 'totalBytes' is constantly at -1 so I cannot calculate/update the progress bar correctly, why would this be happening?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/test.mp3"), @"E:\Test.mp3");
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(bytesIn);

    double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString()); //stays at -1
    label2.Text = Convert.ToString(totalBytes);

    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
    label3.Text = Convert.ToString(percentage);

    progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
}
```

Comment: Try a different file Uri (from some random website). The server you are downloading from probably isn't sending the `Content-Length` header, in which case you can display an indeterminate progress bar instead.

Comment: Was this the problem? If so I can move my comment to an answer so it can be accepted and the question can be closed.

Comment: I believe so, downloading the file using a download manager uses a indeterminate progress bar too, move it to an answer and I will accept:)

Comment: Although its relevant to your question but Why you don't use e.ProgressPercentage for percentage?

Comment: I was to begin with, I was just cycling between some user submitted methods, trying to figure out why I couldn't get it to work correctly :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `WebClient` uses a `WebRequest` internally, and the problem is likely that the server you are downloading the file from is not sending the `Content-Length` HTTP header, in which case you should use a `Indeterminate` ProgressBar style (eg. Marquee).

Answer (score 0):

You can manually check for the Content-Length in the response headers

```
client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]
```