# Determine how far WP WebBrowser has loaded

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

I am working on an alternative browser for Internet Explorer Mobile on Windows Phone. My problem is that I also want a progress bar displaying how far a page has loaded just like Internet Explorer mobile has but I cannot find any property or event on the WebBrowser control that tells me how far a page has loaded. Is there something that I can do?

PS. This project is mainly for Windows Phone 8 so some WP 8 exclusive apis can be used but WP7 support would also be nice.

Answer (score 2):

A loading bar is as simple as determining the total number of kb's to be downloaded at the start of the request and then updating the progress bar with the current downloaded kb's (as a percentage).

Luckily, you can just add a progressbar like this:

```
   <ProgressBar Foreground="Green" x:Name="ProgBar" Visibility="Collapsed" IsIndeterminate="True" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="460" />
```

You then need to modify your `main page.cs` to incorporate the event:

```
 void Browser_Navigating(object sender,     NavigatingEventArgs e)
      {
          ProgBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      }
 void Browser_Navigated(object sender,     System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
      {
          ProgBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      }
```

You can read how this all works [ON THIS LINK](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0524d6/web-browser-control-with-progress-bar-in-windows-phone-7/). (This link shows a tutorial which will exactly explain to you how to accomplish this progress bar)

What you could also do is make use of the `Windows phone 8 Progress Indicator`  [as they do in this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shubham0987/how-to-use-progress-indicator-in-windows-phone/).

Mind you that in general, in C#, (or any programming language) you can ask for the total number of kb's (e.g. with WebClient) [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581820/calculating-total-bytes-to-download-using-webclient). Then you could write a timer that checks the current amount of downloaded kb's and update the progress bar every 0.x seconds.

I hope that helps you out. Good luck!

### Update

If you search for [page loading bar c#](https://www.google.com/search?&q=page+loading+bar+c%23) you get multiple useful links that show you how to build a loading bar for a webbrowser.

For example:

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Custom-Indeterminate-833d783d
- http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/
- [How to make progress bar works while web browser navigating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814523/how-to-make-progress-bar-works-while-web-browser-navigating)
- [How to show progressbar until WP8 WebBrowser control loaded the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449100/how-to-show-progressbar-until-wp8-webbrowser-control-loaded-the-url)

But especially this one could be very useful:

**http://tekkieblog.com/develop-simple-web-browser-with-progress-bar-using-csharp/**

It states that you can use the built-in `Status Strip control` to get the required loading bar. The step to windows phone shouldn't be all that big from this C# snippet.

The proposed method is:

*This simple Tutorial will help in adding up a Progress Bar to your Web browser using C#. In the design view,  drag and drop the Status Strip control from the Tool box. The Status Strip control will be displayed at the bottom of your Form. Select the Status Strip control on the form. Click the Drop Down list and select Progress Bar. The progress bar control will be displayed in your Form.*

*Right click the Web Browser Control in the design mode and select Properties and then select events in the Properties window and move to Progress Changed event and double click it. Add the following code snippet:*

```
private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressBar.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(e.MaximumProgress);
    ProgressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.CurrentProgress);
}
```

So what they basically do is convert the current progress to a number such that you get control over the percentage.

You can also do it differently:

I **HIGHLY RECOMMEND** you watch this link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHQCtunR2QI

That video must definitely answer your question!

Comment: Thanks, I already know about the WP progressbar that doesn't give the specific progress but I want a percentage one. Comparing the amount of download bytes to the total amount sounds like a good idea but how will a WebClient be able to tell me how many bytes the webbrowser control has downloaded at any given moment? Do I somehow need to intercept any request to download webpages and then download them manually with webclient?

Comment: Thanks, but I have actually already searched quite a lot on the matter and have already pickup up the code you provided me with but the problem is that the WebBrowser component in Windows Phone is not the same as that Winforms one and does not provide a progresschanged event or value such as that for me to use. That's why I posted the question here because it seems as if though it will require something very complex to achieve what I am after on Windows Phone.

Comment: @Gerhman: Ah I didn't know that. Unfortunately I can't help you any further on this case then..

Comment: Thanks anyway I appreciate the effort

Answer (score 0):

```
void Browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    ProgBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

void Browser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ProgBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

you have to collapse visiblity of progressbar for more events

1. navigation_failed event
2. browser loaded event not navigated event

Comment: Thanks, but this still isn't really what I am looking for.